# "Unable to find any valuable Window provider" Error

Tags: python, kivy

When I run the following code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label

class Hello(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text = "Hello World")

hello = Hello()
hello.run()
```

I get this error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Sam\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-04-21_43.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Sam\PycharmProjects\kivytut\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Users\Sam\PycharmProjects\kivytut\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\Sam\PycharmProjects\kivytut\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 968, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Users\Sam\PycharmProjects\kivytut\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 272, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 125, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 52, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 60, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I have installed all the dependencies (as far as I'm aware) by executing commands like:

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew 
pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer 
pip install kivy.deps.angle 
pip install –-upgrade kivy﻿
```

and I have uninstalled and reinstalled kivy, but to no avail.

I don't know what is causing this or how to solve it. I have seen many people with similar problems but none of the responses have worked for me. Where do I begin? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issues resulting in this:

1. The dependencies you have installed are in the wrong python.

What IDE are you using?

Your interpreter is in `venv` are you installing the dependencies in this environment? I think this is the issue you have.

2. `kivy.deps.angle` is only available for Python 3.5+ so remove this in any case! This is less likely but still a possibility. You don't need both `angle` and `glew`.

If you can provide more details about your set up and installation I think that might help troubleshoot your problems better.